# C# antivirus block smtp check

Tags: c#

I am trying to check smtp server with the below method.

Seems working fine, but there is a block alert from my antivirus.

Is there anyway to check if the antivirus is blocking and then stop the smtp check?

Thanks.

```
public static bool Check(string host, string port, string username, string password)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            tcpClient.Connect(host, Convert.ToInt32(port));

            NetworkStream netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            System.IO.StreamReader strReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(netStream);
            byte[] WriteBuffer = new byte[1024];
            ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

            WriteBuffer = enc.GetBytes("USER " + username + "\r\n");
            netStream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);

            WriteBuffer = enc.GetBytes("PASS " + password + "\r\n");
            netStream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);

            if (strReader.ReadLine().Contains("+OK"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: ... you want to disable the antivirus SMTP check? Seems like a pretty massive security hole.

Comment: @AlastairPitts I read it as, "Stop *my code from executing if the antivirus is blocking it"

Comment: Yes. It is stop the code if antivirus is blocking

Comment: I am unable to find the exact way to stop it. Therefore I decided to catch the socketexception instead.

Comment: @kyusan93 it acceptable to both post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to find the exact way to stop it. Therefore I decided to catch the socketexception instead.